# How can I render a Paragraph field in the views unformatted template?

Tags: views, paragraphs

I'm simply trying to render a Paragraph field from my content type in a view template. It's insanely difficult! I have the field setup to display the rendered entity, but how do I set it up in my template? Below 'field_question' works fine but 'field_faq_answer', which is the Paragraph field, doesn't render anything.

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set question = row.content['#row']._entity.field_question.value %}
  {% set answer = row.content['#row']._entity.field_faq_answer %}

  {% include 'component--accordion-item.html.twig' with {
    'title': question,
    'uid': random(),
    'content': answer
  }
%}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To render an entity field use the [View filter](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#view) of the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{{ row.content['#row']._entity.field_faq_answer|view }}
```